# LINQ query throw exception on FirstOrDefault method

Tags: entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I'm using EF core, and I have a many-to-many relationship between two entity

IotaProject <--> User

Here's entities & dto related to the question

```
public class IotaProject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Create { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProjectOwnerJoint> Owners { get; set; } = new List<ProjectOwnerJoint>();

}

public class ProjectOwnerJoint
{
    public int IotaProjectId { get; set; }
    public IotaProject IotaProject { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProjectOwnerJoint> OwnedProjects { get; set; } = new List<ProjectOwnerJoint>();
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<IotaProject> IotaProjects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProjectOwnerJoint> ProjectOwnerJoint { get; set; }
}

public class IotaProjectDisplayDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Create { get; set; }

    public UserMinDto Owner { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<UserMinDto> Reviewers { get; set; }
}

public class UserMinDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
}
```

Following LINQ is the problem, the LINQ purpose is to convert IotaProject to IotaProjectDisplayDto, and key part is that Owners property of IotaProject is **ICollection** and Owner property in IotaProjectDisplayDto is just one single element **UserMinDto**, so I only need to get the first element of IotaProject's Owners and that's FirstOrDefault() comes.

```
IEnumerable<IotaProjectDisplayDto> results = _db.IotaProjects.Select(x => new IotaProjectDisplayDto
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                ProjectName = x.ProjectName,
                Create = x.Create,
                Owner = x.Owners.Select(y => y.User).Select(z => new UserMinDto { Id = z.Id, FullName = z.FullName, ShortName = z.ShortName }).FirstOrDefault()
            });
            return results;
```

it throws run-time exception

```
Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ToolHub.Shared.iota.UserMinDto]' cannot be used for parameter 
of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ToolHub.Shared.iota.UserMinDto]' 
of method 'ToolHub.Shared.iota.UserMinDto FirstOrDefault[UserMinDto](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ToolHub.Shared.iota.UserMinDto])' (Parameter 'arg0')
```

I'm guessing it's probably related to deferred execution, but after read some posts, I still can't resolve it.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Right now, the only way I can get this work is I change type of Owner property in IotaProjectDisplayDto into IEnumrable, which will no longer need FirstOrDefault() to immediate execution. And later on, I manually get the first element in the client to display.

Comment: There is discrepancy between the sample LINQ query and the exception. The exception message refers to `List<UserMinDto>` argument of `FirstUserMinDto` method which I don't see in the query. Please provide a real sample which reproduces the issue.

Comment: sorry, it's typo and have updated.

Comment: The sample LINQ query causes N + 1 SQL queries, but does not reproduce the exception. Might be related to EF Core version - I'm using the latest stable 2.2.6, what is the exact version of the EF Core you are using?

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.0.0-preview7.19362.6

Comment: Too bad for you, because many things doesn't work in preview versions. You should use the latest stable 2.x and wait for 3.0 release.

Comment: @IvanStoev holy... I end up downgrade EF core from preview7 to 2.2.6 as you suggested, and everything works...thank you so much for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.0.0-preview7.19362.6

I end up downgrade to EF core stable 2.2.6 as Ivan suggested in comment, and everything works fine.